# Angular material drag drop cdk: Combining items into one and swapping the elements

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-material2, angular-cdk-drag-drop

With reference to Angular CDK Drag & Drop, I'm trying to build something shown in the video below:

https://gyazo.com/218cd5efb6ebe5649ee431a7df47c1e9

I want to achieve two features together: Merging cards and swapping the positions of items. I don't find this feature available in Angular material.

So I tried a hack:

[image]

In this above image assume 1,2,3,4,5,6 are my array values and 0,1,2,3,4,5 are my array indexes.

I tried a logic to identify merge and swap case:
[image]

Note: Added -1 id record before and after the real element.

Merge case is:
from a previousIndexValue > -1 && currentIndexValue > -1 (except before/after of current
element)
else
Swap case

The code is:

```
const previousIndex = event.previousIndex;
    const currentIndex = event.currentIndex;
    const prevSiblingIndex = previousIndex - 1;
    const nextSiblingIndex = previousIndex + 1

    if (currentIndex === prevSiblingIndex || currentIndex === nextSiblingIndex) {
      return true;
    }
    const previousCard = cards[previousIndex].id;
    const currentCard = cards[currentIndex].id;

    if (previousCard === currentCard) {
      return true;
    }

    if (previousCard > -1 && currentCard > -1) { console.log("Merge") }
    else { console.log("Swap"); }
```

The above logic works fine for me if the -1(fake element) has the same height and visible in the container as shown in the video below:

https://youtu.be/1HUOSeyWVPs

But if I hide/opacity = 0/set visibility hidden the logic starts identifying swap as merge.

The above logic doesn't seem to be working for me, whenever I drop the card for swap the above logic gives "Merge".

Here is the demo link: [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhtdnq-khf5td)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom solution since it is not available anywhere

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhtdnq-lexssj

Comment: Hi, thanks, but i think your custom solution is not working as expected?

Comment: It is on Production and works like a charm for us

Comment: It's can be confusing that this stackblitz show nothing. But all you have to do is open the console or uncomment 42 and 45 lines in column.component.ts to get response through alerts. Next, you may want to use transferArrayItem and moveItemInArray to made items move.